# Conflict between Style() and ThemedStyle()

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm using Tkinter and ttk to create a GUI in Python. I want to have two separate themes for the UI that the user can configure. One of these options is the `vista` theme called using the following code:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Style

root = Tk()
root.style = Style()
root.style.theme_use('vista')
```

Another option is the `black` theme called using:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

root = Tk()
root.style = ThemedStyle()
root.style.theme_use('black')
```

I am having some issues because I want users to be able to switch themes while the program is running. Applying these themes separately (i.e., applying a theme, closing the program and applying the other theme on launch) works fine. I start to encounter problems when calling `root.style = ThemedStyle()` followed by `root.style = Style()` somewhere later in the code when switching from the `vista` theme to the `black` theme:

```
    if self.ui_theme == 'Dark':
        self.root.style = ThemedStyle()
        theme = 'black'
        self.root.tk_setPalette(background='#2f3136')
    else:
        self.root.style = Style()
        theme = 'vista'
        self.root.tk_setPalette(background='#f0f0f0')
    self.root.style.theme_use(theme)
```

On top of that, going from `black` to `vista` and back to `black` again causes the following error:

```
error reading package index file C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/ttkthemes/themes/pkgIndex.tcl: Theme plastik already exists
```

which I assume happens when calling `self.root.style = ThemedStyle()` twice in the same instance.

Is there a way to get around this without forcing users to restart the application when applying a new theme? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you once  assing to temporary variable `themedstyle = ThemedStyle()` and later use `self.root.style = themedstyle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `Style()` and `ThemeStyle()` only once at start and assign to variables.

And later assign variable to `root.style`.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.ttk import Style, Button
from ttkthemes import ThemedStyle

def style_1():
    print('winxpblue')
    root.style = s
    root.style.theme_use('winxpblue')

def style_2():
    print('black')
    root.style = t
    root.style.theme_use('black')

root = Tk()

s = Style()
t = ThemedStyle()

#print(s.theme_names())
#print(t.theme_names())

Button(root, text="winxpblue", command=style_1).pack()
Button(root, text="black", command=style_2).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** after testing on Linux I see I don't need `Style()`. I have all themes in `ThemedStyle()`. Maybe on Windows/MacOS it works the same way.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import ttkthemes

root = tk.Tk()

root.style = ttkthemes.ThemedStyle()

for i, name in enumerate(sorted(root.style.theme_names())):
    b = ttk.Button(root, text=name, command=lambda name=name:root.style.theme_use(name))
    b.pack(fill='x')

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be working now. There's still an issue however. When using `ThemedStyle()`, the `vista` UI is much bigger than when just using `Style()`. Any idea what could be causing that? (Let me know if you'd like me to elaborate further).

Comment: I use Linux and I don't have `vista` style. Maybe `ThemedStyle` have own version with some modifications.

Comment: I see. I managed to get around it by creating a new theme called 'light' in the `ttkthemes` folder and modify the black.tcl file to create a light theme. It's not ideal, but it works.